# Passing Knockout viewmodel to the mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I need to pass a knockout viewmodel to the mvc controller how can I achieve that using ajax?

Here is my code:

The model is strongly type object

```
 @model EventWizardViewModel
 @{
     var jsonData = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
 }

  <button data-bind="click: create"> Submit</button>
  <script>
    $(function () {
        $(".date").kendoDateTimePicker({
            value: new Date()
        });
        $("#wizard").smartWizard();

        var vm = ko.mapping.fromJSON('@Html.Raw(jsonData)');
        vm.create = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: {
                    "param":vm
                },
                url: "/CreateEvent/"
            })
            .done(function(data) {

            });
        };
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Is view is strongly-typed with model?

Comment: Show some code first, then we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve that, but fundamentally you usually use a `JSON` call to pass a *data* between fron-end and back-end in, usually, `JSON` format.

[Passing knockout.js observablearray object to MVC Controller Action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846689/passing-knockout-js-observablearray-object-to-mvc-controller-action)

Note in answer the call to `..ko.toJSON(viewModel.AccessLevels)..` to convert observable array to `JSON` string, which will be handled on server side by `MVC` controller of *that* example.